# HTML tags showing up in email text version

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

we just noticed for the emails where we call a table for example that is coded dynamically in the AMPscript block (at the top, outside of the HTML tag), in the text version we can see the HTML (TABLE, TR, TD) along with the copy. It should be only text in the text version.

E.g.

```
%%[
Var @table
Set @table = '
<table>
<tr>
<td>some text</td>
</tr>
</table>
'
]%%
<HTML>
<body>
%%=v(@table)=%%
</body>
</HTML>
```

The result is:

```
<table><tr><td>some text</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using TreatAsContent should resolve that

```
%%[
Var @table
Set @table = '
<table>
<tr>
<td>some text</td>
</tr>
</table>
'
]%%
<HTML>
<body>
%%=treatascontent(v(@table))=%%
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This is exactly right.  Using the V function just outputs the content, where using the treatascontent function will render the content as it would were it a content area in portfolio.  This will show the renderer that the HTML tags are in fact HTML and not text.

Comment: although you don't need the v function inside the treatascontent.  E.g. %%=treatascontent(@table)=%% should work.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't solve the issue. The HTML code from within the AMPscript block from outside the HTML tag still shows up in the plain text email.

Comment: Are you putting the AMPScript directly in the text body of the email or are you leaving the text body blank so that it generates it based on the HTML body?

Comment: it's as per example. The logic is in the AMPscript block outside of the HTML.

Comment: When building an email in the Marketing Cloud, it is possible specify an HTML body and a text body separately.  If you explicitly place AMPScript in the text body tab when creating an email, it will render the AMPScript as it is entered meaning it could contain HTML.  If you don't specify anything in the text tab, then it will render the HTML version then generate the text tab automatically based on the HTML by stripping out all of the tags.